# Assign function with const argument to function pointer with non const argument

Tags: c, function, pointers, gcc, language-lawyer

Note: I have seen [assigning-function-to-function-pointer-const-argument-correctness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56515241/assigning-function-to-function-pointer-const-argument-correctness). While it applies to C++, the accepted answer seems to hint that this shouldn't be an issue.

I have compiled both with `gcc` and `g++` and have the same issue. (g++ gives an error, and gcc a warning, but I assume this is due to different default flags).

A certain static analysis / linter tool we used at work (which shall remain anonymous) is causing this issue. Since the functions don't modify the pointer `int* num` or the data itself, I *should* (must) declare the function args as `const int* const num`.

```
    typedef int (*funcptr)(int* num);
    
    int func1(      int* num)      { return *num +1; }
    int func2(const int* num)      { return *num +1; }
    int func3(      int* const num){ return *num +1; }
    int func4(const int* const num){ return *num +1; }
    
    int main(const int argc, const char** const argv){
        funcptr fptr;
        fptr = func1; //No warning - Signature exactly matches funcptr
        fptr = func2; //WARNING
        fptr = func3; //No warning
        fptr = func4; //WARNING
    }
```

`gcc minimal.c`

```
minimal.c:13:10: warning: assignment to ‘funcptr’ {aka ‘int (*)(int *)’} from incompatible pointer type ‘int (*)(const int *)’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   13 |     fptr = func2;
      |          ^
minimal.c:15:10: warning: assignment to ‘funcptr’ {aka ‘int (*)(int *)’} from incompatible pointer type ‘int (*)(const int * const)’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   15 |     fptr = func4;
```

`g++ minimal.c`

```
minimal.c: In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:
minimal.c:13:12: error: invalid conversion from ‘int (*)(const int*)’ 
to ‘funcptr’ {aka ‘int (*)(int*)’} [-fpermissive]
   13 |     fptr = func2;
      |            ^~~~~
      |            |
      |            int (*)(const int*)
minimal.c:15:12: error: invalid conversion from ‘int (*)(const int*)’ 
to ‘funcptr’ {aka ‘int (*)(int*)’} [-fpermissive]
   15 |     fptr = func4;
      |            ^~~~~
      |            |
      |            int (*)(const int*)
```

**EDIT:** I understand why the standard applies to the above code, thanks to the accepted answer. But why would the following be acceptable?

gcc minimal.c -Wall -Werror

```
int func(const int* const num){ return *num +1; }

int main(const int argc, const char** const argv){
    int aNumber = 4;
    int ret = func(&aNumber);
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function pointer `funcptr` is NOT in fact compatible with `func2`.

Two function types are compatible (ignoring cases including `...` or old-style parameter declarations) if their return types are compatible, they have the same number of arguments, and the arguments types are compatible.  The first two cases are obviously satisfied, so the interesting part is the third case.

When type qualifiers are involved, two types are compatible if they are identically qualified versions of compatible types.  By this definition, a  `const int *` and a `int *` are *not* compatible.  Therefore, `funcptr` and `func2` are not compatible.

While a pointer to a non-qualified type may be converted to a pointer to a qualified version of the same type, by the above rules this does not apply to function parameters.

The rules for compatible qualified types are spelled out in section 6.7.3p10 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> For two qualified types to be compatible, both shall have the
> identically qualified version of a compatible type; the order of type
> qualifiers within a list of specifiers or qualifiers does not affect
> the specified type.

And the rules for compatible function types are listed in section 6.7.6.3p15:

> For two function types to be compatible, **both shall specify compatible
> return types**. Moreover, **the parameter type lists, if both are
> present, shall agree in the number of parameters** and in use of the
> ellipsis terminator; **corresponding parameters shall have compatible
> types.** If one type has a parameter type list and the other type is
> specified by a function declarator that is not part of a function
> definition and that contains an empty identifier list, the parameter
> list shall not have an ellipsis terminator and the type of each
> parameter shall be compatible with the type that results from the
> application of the default argument promotions. If one type has a
> parameter type list and the other type is specified by a function
> definition that contains a (possibly empty) identifier list, both
> shall agree in the number of parameters, and the type of each
> prototype parameter shall be compatible with the type that results
> from the application of the default argument promotions to the type of
> the corresponding identifier. (In the determination of type
> compatibility and of a composite type, each parameter declared with
> function or array type is taken as having the adjusted type and each
> parameter declared with qualified type is taken as having the
> unqualified version of its declared type.)

The parenthesized portion at the end is of particular note.  It basically says that if a parameter is `const` it is omitted for the purpose of determining compatibility.  This is why `func3` doesn't trigger a warning, since a parameter of type `int * const` is equivalent in this context to `int *`.

This does *not* apply to `func2` because what the parameter *points to* is `const`, not the parameter itself.  So a parameter of type `const int *` is *not* adjusted to `int *`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! I am still a little confused as to why the func2 is acceptable, when 3 is not. *Why are the corresponding types compatible for 2, but not for 3?* Is there a rationale behind the standard (what could go wrong?) Or was it just too complex a deduction for a compiler? Restricting the type more should not be an issue?

Comment: @GCon: The quoted text from the standard says “(In the determination of type compatibility and of a composite type, each parameter declared with function or array type is taken as having the adjusted type and each parameter declared with qualified type is taken as having the unqualified version of its declared type.)” In `func3`, the parameter `int * const num` is a `const`-qualifier pointer to `int`, so, for the purpose of determining type compatibility, it is taken as the unqualified version, a pointer to `int`. This then matches the parameter of `func1`, `int *`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - Apologies for still not understanding. Based on the excerpt from the standard **`... declared with a qualified type is taken as having the unqualified version ...`** You mention that `func3(int* const)` would match the type `(*funcptr)(int*)` , as the qualifiers for each parameter discarded. Why would this not apply to e.g. `func2(const int*)` - if the qualifiers are discarded, for the purpose of compatibility, the adjusted type would be `func2(int*)`, matching `funcptr(int*)`.

Comment: @GCon It's the difference between the parameter itself being qualified and what a parameter points to being qualified.

Comment: @dbush - so the unqualified type e.g. of `func4(const int* const)` would be `func4(int* const)` ? I understand now, that this aligns with the standard, but why? Why won't they allow a more constrained/strict function to be assigned to a function pointer of an unqualified type? The caller using `(*funcptr)(&num)` example knows there is no guarantee num won't be modified, yet the implementation guarantees it won't. Is this not the same as `const int num= (int)num2;`

Comment: @GCon A parameter of type `const int* const` would be adjusted to `const int*`.  Since parameters are copied by value, qualifiers on parameters don't make much sense.  Only when pointers point to qualified types does it matter, because both the caller and the callee can refer to the same object.

Comment: @dbush - Thank you. I have written an addendum to the question (which may or may not be worth a separate question). If the issue is allowing both an unqualified pointer and a qualified pointer to exist for the same data, why would the appended code above be allowed?

Comment: @GCon It's allowed to convert a pointer to an unqualified type to a pointer to a qualified type.  That allowance does not extent to converting function types where the parameters differ in the qualified types they point to.

Comment: @GCon: To put it another way, observe that if you have an `x` that is `int *` and you add `const` to it, you are saying you will not change `x`. This makes it `int * const`, not `const int *`. Qualifying a type only changes a thing of that type; it does not change in any way what it points to.

Comment: @GCon: The rules for passing arguments to functions are different from the rules for whether functions are compatible. When passing a pointer argument to a pointer parameter, it is allowed if the unqualified versions of pointed-to types are compatible and the type pointed to by the parameter has all the qualifiers (and maybe more) of the type pointed to by the argument. (This is in the C standard’s rules for simple assignment, which are referred to from the rules for calling a function.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil I completely understand that the rule is from the standard. I cannot understand *why* it is so. I cannot imagine a situation where allowing the assignment of a pointer with stricter arguments could cause any issues. (I can, however, understand the opposite).

Comment: @GCon: I am not clear about what you are asking about assigning to what. The reason a “pointer to a pointer to a non-const“ cannot be implicitly converted to a “pointer to a pointer to const” is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220916/why-isnt-it-legal-to-convert-pointer-to-pointer-to-non-const-to-a-pointer-to). If you have in mind some other conversion, you should clarify.